# Django rest_framework DefaultRouter() class vs normal url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using **REST** in Django, And I couldn't understand what is the main difference between classic URL and instantiating DefaultRouter() for registering URL by ViewSet.

I have a model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey()
```

Serializing model like this:

```
from blog.models import Article


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'author']
```

View Class:

```
from blog.models import Article
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import ArticleSerializer


class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
```

and URLS:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'articles', ArticleViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Is it possible to use classic URL in URLS.py instead of instantiating the object for a ViewSet like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', 'views.someAPI'),
]
```

I just know HTTP method in ViewSet translate methods to retrieve, list and etc...
The Question is can we use traditional(Classic) URL style in this situation, Should we ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in a nutshell as a django developer it is notorious how it is hard to deal with normal urls in django in some cases. Every now and again we get confused with the id type of the detail page that in some case are strings or integers with its regex, and so on.

For example:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(?P<content_type_name>[a-zA-z-_]+)$', views.content_type, name = 'content_type'),
]

# or

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<content_type_name>comics|articles|videos)$', views.content_type, name='content_type'),
]
```

Not mentioning that in almost every case its needed to have two urls like:

> URL pattern: ^users/$ Name: 'user-list'
> URL pattern: ^users/{pk}/$ Name: 'user-detail'

**THE MAIN DIFFERENCE**

However, using DRF routers the example above is done automatically:

```py
# using routers -- myapp/urls.py
router.register(r"store", StoreViewSet, basename="store")
```

How django will understand it:

```
^store/$ [name='store-list']
^store\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='store-list']
^store/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='store-detail']
^store/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='store-detail']
```

See how much job and headache you have saved with a line of code only?

To contrast, according to DRF documentation the `routers` is a type of standard to make it easy to declare urls. A pattern brought from `ruby-on-rails`.

Here is what the documentation details:

> Resource routing allows you to quickly declare all of the common
> routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring
> separate routes for your index... a resourceful route declares them in
> a single line of code.
>
> — Ruby on Rails Documentation

**Django rest framework documentation:**

> Some Web frameworks such as Rails provide functionality for
> automatically determining how the URLs for an application should be
> mapped to the logic that deals with handling incoming requests.
>
> REST framework adds support for automatic URL routing to Django, and
> provides you with a simple, quick and consistent way of wiring your
> view logic to a set of URLs.

[For more details follow the django rest framework documentation.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)

Comment: Nicely explained! 
Probably worth mentioning that we can use DefaultRouter[https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter] as well, which "additionally includes a default API root view, that returns a response containing hyperlinks to all the list views. It also generates routes for optional .json style format suffixes."